# IOS bring activated view controller from background to foreground

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 UIViewControllers, the first controller to load data from server, and then go to the second controller. When 2nd controller needs to fetch more data, it will go back to 1st controller. 1st controller has reference of 2nd, and vice versa.

But when I try to call the 1st controller again from 2nd controller, it shows error 'Application tried to present modally an active controller'

Here is how I call the 1st Controller for 2nd time

```
self.presentViewController(firstController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code also produce the same error

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.bringSubviewToFront(firstController!.view)
```

Comment: You might need to pop the 2nd view from stack if you want the 1st view to appear. Could you elaborate on why you need to go back to the 1st controller when the 2nd needs more data?

Comment: This is not your main problem but it is generally not a good coding stile having two view controllers referencing each other directly unles you use a protocol to de-couple the controllers. 

However, please show more code. How do you "go back to 1st cotroller" using the reference to it?

Comment: @mohonish, if i pop 2nd view, there is possibility that the controller will be destroyed and i don't want that. so 1st controller acts as loading page, when it fetches data from server it will pass the result to 2nd controller

Comment: @HermannKlecker, for 1st to 2nd, i check whether 2nd controller reference not nill. If it is nil, initialize from storyboard and then use self.presentViewController to show it. So what is the best practice to achieve this?